# Android - Issue in facebook sharing using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook sdk to share on the facebook wall. If I'm using the admin account I'm able to share on facebook. Admin account means created app account. If I'm using an other facebook account I'm not able to share.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Below is the code snippet

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID); 
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_actions" };
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", message);
parameters.putString("description", "topic share");

try {
   facebook.request("me");
   String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
   Log.d(TAG, "got response: " + response);       
} catch (Exception e) {       
}
```

Can anyone help to fix this issue?

Thanks
Kamal

Comment: remove you app id from question.

Comment: You seem to be trying to share without user authentication.

Comment: Hi in developer facebook console, on status & review tab i enabled yes to make this app available to public.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: Hi haresh i tested simple facbook app from the above url. I checked admin account its working fine. When i used other facebook account for posting on facebook wall its showing Publish permissions: '[publish_actions]' weren't accepted by user issue. I requested for publish_actions permission but i'm not able to add publish_actions for permissions.